# Язык программирования R: Есть ли годная литература на русском?

Tags: книги, r

Где-то год назад узнал от человека, работающего с геномом, про существование такого крайне удобного для математических и статистических вычислений языка, как R. Возникла идея попробовать применить его для сугубо практических целей, например -- в разработке игр, так как он не только годится для расчётов, но и для удобного вывода обработанной информации.

Однако язык создавался учёными и для учёных, что несколько отразилось на его синтаксисе и принципах работы. Короче говоря, попытка решить с его помощью первую же задачу, отличающуюся по сложности от "Hello, World!", закончилась откровенной неспособностью вкурить в документацию. Если на Хешкоде есть люди, знакомые с этим языком, прошу у вас совета: Есть ли русскоязычные книги и мануалы по R (Викиучебник я уже смотрел, но там только самые азы, и то отрывочно), а также что стоит почитать, чтобы без проблем понимать, что означают мудрёные аргументы тамошних функций (Текущая проблема, например, возникла с генератором случайных чисел, в заданном диапазоне)?

Зимой будут лекции по R на Курсэре, но чтобы хоть что-то из них вынести, тем более -- на английском, в любом случае надо понимать хотя бы терминологию.

Comment: Может эта книга вам как-то поможет: [Наглядная статистика. Используем R!](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7952180/) А еще [вот тут](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4311835) есть подборка, но вроде бы все они на зарубежной мове. Хотя в комментах вроде хвалят

Comment: Совсем недавно вышло [это](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/23816448/). А вообще, если хотите серьезно заниматься R, то учите английский. На английском литературы просто море.

Comment: А больше, кажись, и нету литературы.

Comment: @mikillskegg, может ещё что напишут/переведут, тема-то благодатная. Опять же: Пусть лучше все полезные ссылки складируютсчя в одном топике, а то буду по двадцать раз спрашивать. Как пойму, что разобрался с R -- закрою, а пока пусть весит.

Comment: Оказывается, такой вопрос уже [задавали][1] полтора года назад. В вопросе перечислена ещё пара книг.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/82746/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D1%83-r

Comment: :) Пожалуйста!

Comment: [Подборка](http://r.psylab.info/library/) литературы на английском и русском языках.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я как-то не особо искал изданий на русском языке по R. Иногда находил небольшие pdf с описанием методов + наглядное применение. В основном справка в самой программе или в интернете дают исчерпывающий ответ на все вопросы. К сожалению, только на английском. 
Однако, есть [место](http://r-analytics.blogspot.ru/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2#.Un5tcfn7pWI) где есть кое-какое описание на русском. Довольно много методов и примеров разобрано. Буду рад, если это Вам поможет.

Comment: Нашёл там нужную мне информацию, спасибо. Принимаю, но по прочтении книг могу изменить решение.

Comment: Рад, что помог. Зачастую нужная инфа скрывается не в книжках, а на форумах, блогах и прочих площадках..